# Find value and index of Javascript array element when the index meets another condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
arr1 = [0,1,1,0]
arr2 = [a,b,c,d]
```

I would like to find the values and corresponding indices of arr2[ i ] where i is such that arr1[ i ] != 0 without looping through each position in arr2. What efficient techniques could do something like the following:

```
arr2.forEach( ( 'element with index such that arr1[index] != 0') => {} );
```

** EDIT ** The initial posting of this question wasn't clear about needing to record the indices of the elements that met the condition.

Comment: One way or another you're going to have to iterate through the array to find the non-zero entries.

Comment: The most efficient way would be simple `for`-loop over `arr1`... `for(...) if (arr1[i] === 0) doSomething(arr2[i])`

Comment: If collection you iterate over is (relatively) unchanging, then you can sort on a condition, followed by doing binary search for what you are looking for.

Comment: @Tony sorting is `O(n log n)` followed by a binary search of `O(log n)`, whereas a loop is `O(n)`. I'm not saying your suggestion is wrong, just that it would require *very* specific circumstances for that to be the most efficient.

Comment: I do not know what the actual set interwebjill will be using, nor how it changes during the application s life. That's why I mentioned if it is unchanging. Log n solution might be the most optimal solution, don't Know not enough information

Comment: If strings, then you can hash, store in array and get O 1 (, as an example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution to this is using [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) over the `arra1`:

```js
const arr1 = [0,1,1,0,1];
const arr2 = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

let res = arr1.reduce(
    (acc, v, idx) => v ? acc.concat({val: arr2[idx], idx}) : acc,
    []
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: getting the indices too is easy - updated the answer

You say you don't want to loop through arr2 but what you *could* do is loop through arr1 and collect the respective value of arr2 everytime you get a hit like so:

```
let result = []
arr1.forEach((value, idx) => {
    if (value !== 0) result.push({index: idx, value: arr2[idx]})
}
```

Though this seems like kind of a hack around your requirements.
Other than this I don't think you have another choice but to loop through either array (optimization: only loop through the smallest one).

If you want the complete result you have to check every element of arr2 for the condition because if you don't there *could* still be some elements missing from your result.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `filter`:

```js
arr1 = [0,1,1,0]
arr2 = ['a','b','c','d']

console.log( arr2.filter((item, index) => arr1[index] !== 0) )
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Also, you could just use arr2.filter((c,i) => !!arr1[i]);

Comment: I'd like to capture the index as well as the item. Looking back at my question, I wasn't clear about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce array 1 to the indexes you want and when you need the values you can maps them to their value in array 2

```js
let arr1 = [0, 1, 1, 0];
let arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

let indexes = arr1.reduce((results, val, index) => {
  if (val) {
    results.push(index);
  }
  return results;
}, []);

console.log(indexes);

let vals = indexes.map(idx => arr2[idx]);

console.log(vals);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `$.each()`:

```js
$(function() {
  var arr1 = [0, 1, 1, 0];
  var arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

  $.each(arr1, function(k, v) {
    if (!v) {
      console.log(arr2[k]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Obviously, arrays must be of equal size or `arr1` can be smaller than `arr2`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: why an exemple with jQuery ? Array.forEach is ES5 compliant no ?

Comment: Fully supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach - was just another way to do it.